# How to localize timezone 'z' for a date format "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z"

Tags: java, timezone, locale, datetime-format

I want to format current date in `MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z` format based on locale.

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new  Locale("ja", "JP"));
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Output:

> 04/01/2018 17:15:23 午後 EDT

I want to display EDT in Japanese too. If I try `zzzz` instead of `z` in 
the pattern, then timezone is localized and displays "Eastern Daylight Time" in Japanese:

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a zzzz";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new  Locale("ja", "JP"));
Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Output:

> 04/01/2018 17:20:17 午後 東部夏時間

How can we localize the Timezone abbreviation 'EDT' and display in Japanese?

Comment: Is there even such a thing as an acronym in Japanese? How would you abbreviate `東部夏時間`?

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `SimpleDateFormat` class. It is not only long outdated, it is also notoriously troublesome. Today we have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: My test with `java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter` seems to indicate that format pattern letter `z`, and from Java 9 letter `v` too, outputs the localized time zone abbreviation, in German for example MEZ/MESZ instead of CET/CEST. So probably there is no Japanese translation of EDT.

Answer (score 1):

The localized strings are built-in in the JVM, but you can replace them by getting the `DateFormatSymbols` from the formatter and changing it:

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss a z";
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern, new Locale("ja", "JP"));
DateFormatSymbols symbols = dateFormat.getDateFormatSymbols();
String[][] zones = symbols.getZoneStrings();
for (int i = 0; i < zones.length; i++) {
    // position 4 is the abbreviation for Daylight Saving Time
    String zoneAbbrev = zones[i][4];
    // overwrite zone short names (replace EDT with whatever string you want)
    if ("EDT".equals(zoneAbbrev)) {
        zones[i][2] = "東部夏時間"; // change it to the short name for Standard Time
        zones[i][4] = "東部夏時間"; // change it to the short name for Daylight Saving Time
    }
}
symbols.setZoneStrings(zones);
dateFormat.setDateFormatSymbols(symbols);
```

I don't know what should be the correct strings, so I used the same as above, but you can replace them with the correct values: `zones[i][2]` contains the short name for EST (Standard Time) and `zones[i][4]` contains the short name for EDT (Daylight Saving Time).

Answer (score -2):

If you're allowed to use external libraries, then please use [Apache Commons DateUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DateUtils.html) method:

```
public static Calendar toCalendar(Date date, TimeZone tz)
```

To create the calendar document from your date and manipulate it after.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a specific way how to convert a Date to a String, and not parse it (opposite direction).

Comment: @Lodovik, you're right, thanks. I originally copied the wrong method. I fixed it now.

Comment: I still don’t get how this would give the OP a Japanese translation of EDT. What am I missing? Could you explain better? @AR1